# Bulk Email with Swiftmailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer, bulk-email

I am using [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) to send bulk emails. At the moment, I do it with the code

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('*****', 25);
$transport->setUsername('***');
$transport->setPassword('***');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setSubject($derBetreff);

$bbc= array('1@web.de','2@web.de','3@web.de',...,'1000@web.de');

$message->setFrom(array('my@email.de' => 'My Name'));           
$message->setTo('my@email.de');
$message->setBcc($bcc);
$message->setBody('Hi this is my email');           
$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('myFile.pdf'));     

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
echo $result;
```

where I only send a single email to myself and add ~1000 people in the BCC.

It takes about 9 minutes to execute the code and send one single email and it returns a 'success' message. However, my *max_execution_time* in my php.ini file is only set to 30 seconds.

**My first question is: Why does the max_execution_time not stop my SwiftMailer script?**

Secondy, I found the [AntiFlood Plugin for Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html#antiflood-plugin) which helps to send bulk emails. The script below sends each member a single email by sending 100 emails first and then pause for 30 seconds and continuing sending the next 100 emails and so on. I have read that this is good practice to circumvent being marked as spam.

**My second question is: Does the AntiFlood Plugin need an extraordinary long execution time in order to work?** For example, if I send 1000 emails with the script given below and only take the pausing into consideration, then the script runs already at least 4.5 minutes, right?

```
// Create the Mailer using any Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance(
  Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.example.org', 25)
);

// Use AntiFlood to re-connect after 100 emails
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin(100));

// And specify a time in seconds to pause for (30 secs)
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin(100, 30));

// Continue sending as normal
for ($lotsOfRecipients as $recipient) {
  ...

  $mailer->send( ... );
}
```

Comment: Hi, I need to complete this exact thing, how did you end up doing it?

Comment: @LeeWiggins you can safly use the Anti-Flood Plugin or even better a mail query. I added an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47922195/2311074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the sending of the emails does not happen in the script itself. That is why the max_execution_time is not affected if your server runs on Linux, see the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

> The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive
>   max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script
>   itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution
>   of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations,
>   database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum
>   time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows
>   where the measured time is real.

Thus using the [Anti-Flood](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/plugins.html#antiflood-plugin) Plugin is a good idea when you send multiple mails at once.

However, I think better practice is to store the emails in a database and let a cronjob send X mails from the DB every Y minutes. This way, you do not have a loading script that takes several minutes in front of you (included with the danger of resending if the page gets reloaded). If you use a framework like Laravel, then you could use the build-in [mail-query](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#queueing-mail) feature which does exactly that.

Comment: $result = $mailer->send($message);
echo $result;
My question is  the echo command is waiting for the mailer to complete. In this case shall the php script takes very long ?

Answer (score 0):

To send bulk email, You should use a Broker service like RabbitMQ. You have to create 2 queues, one for pooling emails and the other to send email with Swiftmailer. Each email will be a rabbitMq Message.

Comment: We are using this method successfully in a project that sends thousands of emails a day. The application writes to the queue, and forgets about it. The rabbitmq consumers read the request and sends the emails when it has time to do it,

Comment: I'd upvote you, if your answer had more substance to allow the poster to get in the way with